# Connecting Access Database to Lazarus Pascal 1.6.2

Tags: ms-access, dns, connection, pascal, lazarus

I am trying to connect pascal too an access database after creating the SystemDNS ODBC connection as LazConnect to the database i get this error connecting to the database here is the code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ODBCConnection1.DatabaseName:='LazConnect';
ODBCConnection1.UserName:='Admin';
ODBCConnection1.Transaction:=SQLTransaction1;
SQLTransaction1.Database:=ODBCConnection1;
SQLQuery1.Database:=ODBCConnection1;
SQLQuery1.Transaction:=SQLTransaction1;
SQLQuery1.UsePrimaryKeyAsKey:=False;
SQLQuery1.SQL.Text:='SELECT * FROM Student';
Datasource1.dataset:=SQLQuery1;
DBGrid1.DataSource:=DataSource1;
ODBCConnection1.Open;
If ODBCConnection1.Connected then
end;
```

Here is the error:

https://gyazo.com/df817d537f8b8fc68c6fc6850d77acb0

It says the Give DNS has an invalid architecture between the driver and application-

Searched everywhere can not find anything.

Comment: The error means you're trying to load a 64-bit driver into a 32-bit process (or vice versa).

Comment: @matti G - why you didn't translate the error ? Lazy guy ;) I am Polish, so i understood that, but what about other users ? hm ?